# Similar functions applied to nested list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Here is the problem I encountered. 
I have some functions that are similar in their bodies (with a slightly difference), but they have signatures.

```hs
flatB :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
flatB []  = []
flatB [x] = [x]
flatB (a : b : xs) | isDigit (head n) = replicate (read n :: Int) a ++ flatB xs
                   | otherwise = a : flatB (b : xs)
    where n = head b

flatC :: [String] -> [String]
flatC []  = []
flatC [x] = [x]
flatC (a : b : xs) | isDigit (head b) = replicate (read b :: Int) a ++ flatC xs
                   | otherwise = a : flatC (b : xs)
```

I'm expecting the function to do the following:

```hs
> flatC ["a","2","b"]
["a","a","b"]

> flatB [["a","b"],["2"]]
[["a","b"],["a","b"]]
```

The code above works. But I'm wondering whether there is a simpler way to achieve this?

I think that creating a *typeclass* may be the way, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Are List the kind of data structure you need to use? from what I see I'd say you have and objects of type `a` and times you need to replicate them. That is a structure similar to `(a, Int)`. The `flat` function would have the signature `flat :: [(a,Int)] -> [a]`

Comment: @lsmor  I'm afraid that the numbers are the `String` type and they are mixed with other non-number Strings in the List. So what troubles me is actually converting `[[Int]]` or `[Int]` to `Int` in a nested list :(

Comment: If your input has two different shapes (`[[Int]]` or `[Int]`) then you can create a type class with a `flat` method and two instances, one for nested and one for unnested list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is how you read the `Int` out of every other element on the list, which you can factor out as a function parameter:

```hs
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

flat :: (a -> Maybe Int) -> [a] -> [a]
flat _ []  = []
flat _ [x] = [x]
flat readElem (a : b : xs)
  | Just n <- readElem b = replicate n a ++ flat readElem xs
  | otherwise = a : flat readElem (b : xs)

flatB :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
flatB = flat readHead
  where
    readHead [] = Nothing
    readHead (n : _) = readMaybe n

flatC :: [String] -> [String]
flatC = flat readMaybe
```